# No output from httr::GET

Tags: r, get, rvest, httr

I am trying to extract the Options table from [NSE](https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain).

I have tried,

```
headers = c(
  `authority` = 'www.nseindia.com',
  `path` = '/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY',
  `scheme` = 'https',
  `accept` = '*/*',
  `User-Agent` = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36',
  `sec-ch-ua-platform` = 'Windows',
  `method` = 'GET',
  `Sec-Fetch-Site` = 'same-origin',
  `Sec-Fetch-Mode` = 'cors',
  `Sec-Fetch-Dest` = 'empty',
  `Accept-Language` = 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  `cookie` = 'nsit=tLBMrG-CG3scilZijKQDc2tm; AKA_A2=A; ak_bmsc=8B1EEE3EE094F8354C2CD8449AAA8BDC~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQPB0gF42ipld8AQAAC+9nfQ25egBTI4D06iCJzwyoqQIa753psweltDT93W8W5w+9qw7m3MLhBLZ1knTNOuxMC/0TEEFYU+mOJMSo6gb3j1GCD0j7rVC2jEAK/C1UxOjvtEMS9BgtbhoJ/jDLsjhaUU5iea4me272sQpod47HIVcBBKiTgKy/nRMHQGI/p6iY54NTOe6iFrCIiOoWijnF4X2Jz1TPzcwnx1lMap8XFUSbmTPS06QzdBgUG5fakhvCV9P/Np6w4adZlp5kzbeWY6Kn4WlpGdNo+QgyfdjUHyxJ7GOkwxFs32N80lyBszFq82JW5bdqvFJGIK7b5ySdmPhPsEvAb8cjRt+e8ObRFlH8OCHM7ymN4xhlFveJC0sSs3ziNB1NlTOA; nseappid=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhcGkubnNlIiwiYXVkIjoiYXBpLm5zZSIsImlhdCI6MTYzNDE5MTU2MywiZXhwIjoxNjM0MTk1MTYzfQ.Ty3XPURICRwyAzAmSt7D5nUtx45IFA5WqzM-q_dC2i0; bm_mi=D3B561A092C33DADD10DBA65C6E094AC~XJwOyCM3+CExcMdtbTIh+LZ7iXvGSkqlUosgCeq0LCP4YsQ+njtQVB6EHxBXYZfNupGLS56q2T2jC4NYl43eZUXJvAMRdAgGY9VxUt5jBpv8xJ7o2d0EfSsRgbcEk7xsJ8ntWdyJHXQQRzJstlDzst2gPDHrYFuxPiPiuXb8gqpNCHDq9Xu9ek7twzFUeRr1RLc7wZlLildMpwgny5pPgiWdUTZ6PRUO6aTD/hvvC9M=; bm_sv=83594C0C6A596CBFACAB013DE8D796EE~2QkpSgBZhUD7HJYIpBrs1RiRuEq0Lu8ktHU3CGUVEJ2DS9LdqBewGGyXAepjmDOgNVsoBB2FqAqiSCx7XipGPLErLDi7weN2SeHA8xMXou5Bygz1300C0vWwLM8kEMxpKeUHrKz8NqqrSTf2LSLXNple3ffn/4gz+08l3khrh0U='
)

params = list(
  `symbol` = 'NIFTY'
)

res <- httr::GET(url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), query = params)
```

But I am unable to get any output and it's struck,

[image]

I have also tried using `read_html` from `rvest`.

Any solutions?
Thank you

Comment: I have the same thing with ```url <- "https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain" page <- url %>% read_html()``` Maybe you will try to use ```RSelenium```?

Comment: Can get table from `RSelenium` but wanted from `httr` or `rvest`.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the code with ```RSelenium```. It will be intersting to see.

Comment: Well, can't get the table from `RSelenium` either. Table is not displayed

Comment: scraping is disallowed https://www.nseindia.com/robots.txt

Comment: Wow. We can see robots.txt by every site? But you can work with .csv file from there

Comment: Yeah we can see the robots file from nearly every site. The .csv file also can't be downloaded.

Comment: I can download, hm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238142/discussion-between-nad-pat-and-manro).